# Local NSEvent Monitor yields incorrect keycode

Tags: macos, appkit, keycode, nsevent

I'm using a local monitor to observe key events. However, I get an incorrect keycode when the modifiers ⌥ and ⌘ are active and the key with code 42 is pressed simultaneously. The keyCode in the event is 8, which is C on my keyboard. The event monitor is used within a subclass of NSTextField to intercept key events.

This is the only case where I get an incorrect keycode so far.  I also tried using a CGEventTap to reproduce this, but the keyCode is always correct using a CGEventTap.

Has anybody ever experienced this? Is this a known bug?

`import Foundation
import Cocoa`

`class FooTextField : NSTextField {`

```
func initMonitor() {
    NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.keyUp, .keyDown, .flagsChanged], handler: onKeyEvent)
}

private func onKeyEvent(_ e: NSEvent) -> NSEvent? {
    //prints 8 when key with keycode 42 is pressed and (⌥,⌘) are active.
    //the textfield seems to receives the correct keycode since a # appears for German keyboards
    print(e.keyCode)
    return e
}
```

}

Comment: What version of macOS? How exactly are you determining the key code from the event? Key code 42 should correspond to the key in the location where the backslash `\\` key is on an ANSI keyboard, rightmost in the top row of letter keys. That's the one you're pressing? Are you using a U.S. keyboard or one from/for another country? If you're looking at an `NSEvent`, what happens if you obtain its `CGEvent` and examine the key code of that? If you run your app with the `NSTraceEvents` user default set to true, what gets traced? (E.g. /path/to/YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApp -NSTraceEvents YES`.)

Comment: Thx for your response.
1.: I'm using MacOs Mojave. 
2.: I'm using a German keyboard, but yes, it should be \ on ANSI keyboards. It's # on German keyboards.
3.: The CGEvent's keyCode is 8, just like the NSEvent's one.
4.: I do not notice anything suspicious in the traced events.

Comment: It is worth noticing that I'm running a CGEventTap on the Main thread. However, the tap is disabled while the NSTextField is the first responder and this does not cause any problems with any other key.

Comment: I've also got to say that I do not know what to look for in the trace event log. There are many things going on there, especially the CGEventTap seems to be very verbose. But since every mouse event is tracked here, it is kind of hard to identify anything. Is there any hint about what to look for you can give me?

Comment: Do you have any third-party key remapping software installed? Could there be another local event monitor in your process (maybe from a third-party library) that's modifying the event?

Comment: Well, you can look for the KeyDown event and see if the key code is matches what you're seeing in your code. You could also launch TextEdit with tracing in the same way and see what it gets for that key combination.

Comment: Made sure BetterTouchTool and Alfred are not running, this does not change anything. I do want to note here that my CGEventTap - a global monitor for events which is *at least supposed to be* disabled when the local monitor is running - does always identify the keycode correctly, no matter which modifiers are active. I also determined that ⌥ is the modifier causing this problem, ⌘ has no influence on this. I'm going to try to disable the global event monitoring completely to make sure it isn't my global monitor that causes this weird behaviour.

Comment: FYI: Disabling the global monitor did not change anything.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Just did it. Use initMonitor() to get started.

Comment: I tried your code and I get keycode 42 but ‘ appears in the text field instead of #. Which Input Source do you use? Did you try the on-screen keyboard?

Comment: This gets weirder with every research attempt. Yes, you are right, ‘ should appear. 
I use an German-layout Apple keyboard with numpad. I never tried using the on-screen keyboard, but I'll give it a shot when I'm home, thanks for the proposal.